# use logger in scala pipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the code below.  It comes from the blog post:

http://www.sparktutorials.net/Spark+MLLib+-+Predict+Store+Sales+with+ML+Pipelines

I'm trying to forecast store sales with linear regression.  I'm doing some data cleansing and then creating a ml pipeline.  I'm a total scala newbee.  I have a piece of the spark-shel messages that print to the screen when I run the script.  I post the piece where it starts throwing errors.  Can someone please let me know what the issue is and how to fix it?  All tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
// loading packages
// from example: http://www.sparktutorials.net/Spark+MLLib+-+Predict+Store+Sales+with+ML+Pipelines

import org.apache.log4j.{Logger}
//core and SparkSQL
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
// ML Feature Creation, Tuning, Models, and Model Evaluation
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.{RegressionEvaluator}
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.{LinearRegression}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics


// preprocessing & preparing Pipelines

// Indexers & Encoders

val stateHolidayIndexer = new StringIndexer()
.setInputCol("StateHoliday")
.setOutputCol("StateHolidayIndex")


val schoolHolidayIndexer = new StringIndexer()
.setInputCol("SchoolHoliday")
.setOutputCol("SchoolHolidayIndex")
val stateHolidayEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
.setInputCol("StateHolidayIndex")
.setOutputCol("StateHolidayVec")
val schoolHolidayEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
.setInputCol("SchoolHolidayIndex")
.setOutputCol("SchoolHolidayVec")
val dayOfMonthEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
.setInputCol("DayOfMonth")
.setOutputCol("DayOfMonthVec")
val dayOfWeekEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
.setInputCol("DayOfWeek")
.setOutputCol("DayOfWeekVec")
val storeEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
.setInputCol("Store")
.setOutputCol("StoreVec")


// assemble all vectors in to one vector to input to Model

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols(Array("StoreVec", "DayOfWeekVec", "Open", "DayOfMonthVec", "StateHolidayVec", "SchoolHolidayVec"))
.setOutputCol("features")

// Pipeline

def preppedLRPipeline():TrainValidationSplit = {
val lr = new LinearRegression()

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
.addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
.addGrid(lr.fitIntercept)
.addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0))
.build()

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
.setStages(Array(stateHolidayIndexer, schoolHolidayIndexer,stateHolidayEncoder, schoolHolidayEncoder, storeEncoder,dayOfWeekEncoder, dayOfMonthEncoder, assembler, lr))

val tvs = new TrainValidationSplit()
.setEstimator(pipeline)
.setEvaluator(new RegressionEvaluator)
.setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
.setTrainRatio(0.75)
tvs
}


// bringing in data and removing null values

def loadTrainingData(sqlContext:HiveContext):DataFrame = {
val trainRaw = sqlContext
.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
    // path to training data
    // .load("../mlproject/rossman/train.csv")
.load("/Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clint/store_forecast/input/train.csv")
.repartition(6)
trainRaw.registerTempTable("raw_training_data")

sqlContext.sql("""SELECT
    double(Sales) label, double(Store) Store, int(Open) Open, double(DayOfWeek) DayOfWeek,
    StateHoliday, SchoolHoliday, (double(regexp_extract(Date, '\\d+-\\d+-(\\d+)', 1))) DayOfMonth
    FROM raw_training_data
  """).na.drop()
}

def loadKaggleTestData(sqlContext:HiveContext) = {
val testRaw = sqlContext
.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
    // load test data
    // .load("../mlproject/rossman/test.csv")
.load("/Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clint/store_forecast/input/test.csv")
.repartition(6)
testRaw.registerTempTable("raw_test_data")

val testData = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT
    Id, double(Store) Store, int(Open) Open, double(DayOfWeek) DayOfWeek, StateHoliday,
    SchoolHoliday, (double(regexp_extract(Date, '\\d+-\\d+-(\\d+)', 1))) DayOfMonth
    FROM raw_test_data
    WHERE !(ISNULL(Id) OR ISNULL(Store) OR ISNULL(Open) OR ISNULL(DayOfWeek)
      OR ISNULL(StateHoliday) OR ISNULL(SchoolHoliday))
  """).na.drop() // weird things happen if you don't filter out the null values manually

Array(testRaw, testData) // got to hold onto testRaw so we can make sure
  // to have all the prediction IDs to submit to kaggle
}


// save predictions

def savePredictions(predictions:DataFrame, testRaw:DataFrame) = {
val tdOut = testRaw
.select("Id")
.distinct()
.join(predictions, testRaw("Id") === predictions("PredId"), "outer")
.select("Id", "Sales")
.na.fill(0:Double) // some of our inputs were null so we have to
                       // fill these with something
tdOut
.coalesce(1)
.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
    // save predictions
.save("linear_regression_predictions.csv")
//.save("/Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clint/store_forecast/Output/linear_regression_predictions.csv")
}

// fitting and testing

def fitModel(tvs:TrainValidationSplit, data:DataFrame) = {
val Array(training, test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 12345)
logger.info("Fitting data")
val model = tvs.fit(training)
logger.info("Now performing test on hold out set")
val holdout = model.transform(test).select("prediction","label")

  // have to do a type conversion for RegressionMetrics
val rm = new RegressionMetrics(holdout.rdd.map(x =>(x(0).asInstanceOf[Double], x(1).asInstanceOf[Double])))

logger.info("Test Metrics")
logger.info("Test Explained Variance:")
logger.info(rm.explainedVariance)
logger.info("Test R^2 Coef:")
logger.info(rm.r2)
logger.info("Test MSE:")
logger.info(rm.meanSquaredError)
logger.info("Test RMSE:")
logger.info(rm.rootMeanSquaredError)

model
}


// linear Regression

val data = loadTrainingData(sqlContext)
val Array(testRaw, testData) = loadKaggleTestData(sqlContext)

// The linear Regression Pipeline
val linearTvs = preppedLRPipeline()
logger.info("evaluating linear regression")
val lrModel = fitModel(linearTvs, data)
logger.info("Generating kaggle predictions")
val lrOut = lrModel.transform(testData)
.withColumnRenamed("prediction","Sales")
.withColumnRenamed("Id","PredId")
.select("PredId", "Sales")
savePredictions(lrOut, testRaw)
```

spark-shell output:

```
warning: there were two deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
loadKaggleTestData: (sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext)Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]
savePredictions: (predictions: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, testRaw: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)Unit
<console>:146: error: not found: value logger
       logger.info("Fitting data")
       ^
<console>:148: error: not found: value logger
       logger.info("Now performing test on hold out set")
```

Update:

```
//package net.sparktutorials.examples

import org.apache.log4j.{Logger}
//core and SparkSQL
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
// ML Feature Creation, Tuning, Models, and Model Evaluation
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.{RegressionEvaluator}
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.{RandomForestRegressor, LinearRegression}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics


object RossmannRegression extends Serializable {
  @transient lazy val logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  val stateHolidayIndexer = new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol("StateHoliday")
    .setOutputCol("StateHolidayIndex")
  val schoolHolidayIndexer = new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol("SchoolHoliday")
    .setOutputCol("SchoolHolidayIndex")
  val stateHolidayEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("StateHolidayIndex")
    .setOutputCol("StateHolidayVec")
  val schoolHolidayEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("SchoolHolidayIndex")
    .setOutputCol("SchoolHolidayVec")
  val dayOfMonthEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("DayOfMonth")
    .setOutputCol("DayOfMonthVec")
  val dayOfWeekEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("DayOfWeek")
    .setOutputCol("DayOfWeekVec")
  val storeEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("Store")
    .setOutputCol("StoreVec")

  val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("StoreVec", "DayOfWeekVec", "Open",
      "DayOfMonthVec", "StateHolidayVec", "SchoolHolidayVec"))
    .setOutputCol("features")

  def preppedLRPipeline():TrainValidationSplit = {
    val lr = new LinearRegression()

    val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
      .addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
      .addGrid(lr.fitIntercept)
      .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0))
      .build()

    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(stateHolidayIndexer, schoolHolidayIndexer,
        stateHolidayEncoder, schoolHolidayEncoder, storeEncoder,
        dayOfWeekEncoder, dayOfMonthEncoder,
        assembler, lr))

    val tvs = new TrainValidationSplit()
      .setEstimator(pipeline)
      .setEvaluator(new RegressionEvaluator)
      .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
      .setTrainRatio(0.75)
    tvs
  }

  def preppedRFPipeline():TrainValidationSplit = {
    val dfr = new RandomForestRegressor()

    val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
      .addGrid(dfr.minInstancesPerNode, Array(1, 5, 15))
      .addGrid(dfr.maxDepth, Array(2, 4, 8))
      .addGrid(dfr.numTrees, Array(20, 50, 100))
      .build()

    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(stateHolidayIndexer, schoolHolidayIndexer,
        stateHolidayEncoder, schoolHolidayEncoder, storeEncoder,
        dayOfWeekEncoder, dayOfMonthEncoder,
        assembler, dfr))

    val tvs = new TrainValidationSplit()
      .setEstimator(pipeline)
      .setEvaluator(new RegressionEvaluator)
      .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
      .setTrainRatio(0.55)
    tvs
  }

  def fitModel(tvs:TrainValidationSplit, data:DataFrame) = {
    val Array(training, test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 12345)
    logger.info("Fitting data")
    val model = tvs.fit(training)
    logger.info("Now performing test on hold out set")
    val holdout = model.transform(test).select("prediction","label")

    // have to do a type conversion for RegressionMetrics
    val rm = new RegressionMetrics(holdout.rdd.map(x =>
      (x(0).asInstanceOf[Double], x(1).asInstanceOf[Double])))

    logger.info("Test Metrics")
    logger.info("Test Explained Variance:")
    logger.info(rm.explainedVariance)
    logger.info("Test R^2 Coef:")
    logger.info(rm.r2)
    logger.info("Test MSE:")
    logger.info(rm.meanSquaredError)
    logger.info("Test RMSE:")
    logger.info(rm.rootMeanSquaredError)

    model
  }

  def savePredictions(predictions:DataFrame, testRaw:DataFrame, filePath:String) = {
    val tdOut = testRaw
      .select("Id")
      .distinct()
      .join(predictions, testRaw("Id") === predictions("PredId"), "outer")
      .select("Id", "Sales")
      .na.fill(0:Double) // some of our inputs were null so we have to
                         // fill these with something
    tdOut
      .coalesce(1)
      .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(filePath)
  }

  def loadTrainingData(sqlContext:HiveContext, filePath:String):DataFrame = {
    val trainRaw = sqlContext
      .read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      //.load(filePath)
      .load("/Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clnt/store_forecast/input/train.csv")
      .repartition(30)
    trainRaw.registerTempTable("raw_training_data")

    sqlContext.sql("""SELECT
      double(Sales) label, double(Store) Store, int(Open) Open, double(DayOfWeek) DayOfWeek,
      StateHoliday, SchoolHoliday, (double(regexp_extract(Date, '\\d+-\\d+-(\\d+)', 1))) DayOfMonth
      FROM raw_training_data
    """).na.drop()
  }

  def loadKaggleTestData(sqlContext:HiveContext, filePath:String) = {
    val testRaw = sqlContext
      .read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      //.load(filePath)
      .load("/Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clnt/store_forecast/input/test.csv")
      .repartition(30)
    testRaw.registerTempTable("raw_test_data")

    val testData = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT
      Id, double(Store) Store, int(Open) Open, double(DayOfWeek) DayOfWeek, StateHoliday,
      SchoolHoliday, (double(regexp_extract(Date, '\\d+-\\d+-(\\d+)', 1))) DayOfMonth
      FROM raw_test_data
      WHERE !(ISNULL(Id) OR ISNULL(Store) OR ISNULL(Open) OR ISNULL(DayOfWeek)
        OR ISNULL(StateHoliday) OR ISNULL(SchoolHoliday))
    """).na.drop() // weird things happen if you don't filter out the null values manually

    Array(testRaw, testData) // got to hold onto testRaw so we can make sure
    // to have all the prediction IDs to submit to kaggle
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val name = "Linear Regression Application"
    logger.info(s"Starting up $name")

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(name)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
//    sc.setLogLevel("INFO")

    logger.info("Set Up Complete")
    val data = loadTrainingData(sqlContext, args(0))
    val Array(testRaw, testData) = loadKaggleTestData(sqlContext, args(1))

    // The linear Regression Pipeline
    val linearTvs = preppedLRPipeline()
    logger.info("evaluating linear regression")
    val lrModel = fitModel(linearTvs, data)
    logger.info("Generating kaggle predictions")
    val lrOut = lrModel.transform(testData)
      .withColumnRenamed("prediction","Sales")
      .withColumnRenamed("Id","PredId")
      .select("PredId", "Sales")
    //savePredictions(lrOut, testRaw, "linear_predictions.csv")
    savePredictions(lrOut, testRaw, "/Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clnt/store_forecast/Output/linear_predictions.csv")
  }
}
```

Code in spark-shell:

```
:load /Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clnt/simple_spark_regression
```

output:

```
Loading /Users/username/Desktop/stuff/comp/clnt/simple_spark_regression...
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.{RandomForestRegressor, LinearRegression}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics
warning: there were 10 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
defined object RossmannRegression
```

Comment: You are missing some code, e.g. the whole main method. There is a link to github on the page that has everything though (https://github.com/anabranch/simple-spark-regression/blob/master/src/main/scala/regression.scala).

Comment: @Shaido thank you for the tip.  I've added an update to my original post with the complete code.  Also I've tried running the script in spark-shell with ": load" I get several warnings but it doesn't output the final csv or print any of the logger steps to the screen.  Is there something I'm missing when I try to run the script?